# How to convert For loop into a While loop

Tags: python

```
def file_read ():
  dictionary = {}
  state      = ""
  capital    = ""
  flag       = 0
  with open("state_capitals.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f:
        if flag == 0:
            state = line.rstrip('\n')
            flag = 1
        elif flag == 1:
            capital = line.rstrip('\n')
            flag = 0
        dictionary[state] = capital
  print(dictionary)
```

How would I use a while loop to make the dictionary instead of the for loop. Code works perfectly fine but professor insists I use a while loop.

Comment: You can store each line in a list and use while loop with index, which breaks if the index is equal or greater than the length of the list

Comment: There are over 28,000 search results for ["for loop to while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+for+loop+to+while+loop) when searching under the [python] tag; perhaps one of these existing Q&As will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def file_read():
    dictionary = {}
    state = ""
    capital = ""
    flag = 0
    with open("state_capitals.txt", "r") as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if flag == 0:
                state = line.rstrip('\n')
                flag = 1
            elif flag == 1:
                capital = line.rstrip('\n')
                flag = 0
            dictionary[state] = capital
    print(dictionary)
```